# "Cannot access a disposed object"

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a problem while accessing a association object from linq to sql.
I have a class Article and User. Each Article has a seller (which is a User) and each user has many Articles. I solved that with an association.

This is how my linq to sql classes looks like:
[image: linq to sql classes]

And this is the association:

[image: association]

Here is the code behind the Article.Seller:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="User_Article", Storage="_Seller", ThisKey="SellerID", OtherKey="ID", IsForeignKey=true)]
public User Seller
{
    get
    {
        return this._Seller.Entity;
    }
    set
    {
                   ...
    }
}
```

Now, when I want to get the Seller of an Article, I get the following error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DataContext accessed
>   after Dispose.'.

The error occurs in the get of seller.

Any ideas how to handle this?

EDIT: Heres' the code where DataContext is used:

```
public static List<Article> Read()
{
    using (uDataContext dbx = new uDataContext())
    {
        return dbx.Article.ToList();
    }
}
```

The list is used as following:

```
List<Article> articles = ArticleDALC.Read();

foreach (Article article in articles)
{
    // Exception appears here!
    User seller = article.Seller;
    ....
}
```

Comment: It's because the context from which the data comes from is disposed. You'll need to show the code that does the get.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I added the code that does the get!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution found:

Simply set the `DeferredLoadingEnabled` property on false when using the DataContext:

```
public static List<Article> Read()
{
    using (uDataContext dbx = new uDataContext())
    {
        dbx.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
        return dbx.Article.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't dispose your DataContext.

All LINQ objects are associated with a DataContext. You're probably accessing the object outside the `using` block where the DataContext is created.